# Flutter how to guarante minimum left space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let me provide an image:

[image]

I have a rectangle. I put here two elements, O1 and TEXT (with `TextAlign.center`).

For now I'm using stack, so in rectangle I have:

1. `text` in `container`, `expanded` on whole width with `TextAlign.Center`
2. Small rectangle on right (O1) on screen. (`positioned` widget with `left: 0`)

All works fine but, in some cases, If text is long, text overlap O1 - **it's a problem.**

**How to assure a minimum left starting position for text which will work on long text (text which want to overlap O1)?**  i.e if text want to overlap O1, then move text to right. (O1 width = 16)

**What I tried?**

Add left margin / padding to container of text.
It works fine for long text which wants to overlap O1. But It does not work properly on smaller text. Because `TextAlign.center` applies after text to right. So this text does not looks center in the biggest rectangle, only in the smaller.

Comment: Instead of explaining your code add some helpful code snippet you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overflow in Text Widget.

```
new Text(
      'Text largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontSize: 13.0,
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        color: new Color(0xFF212121),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
```

Just try the methods [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/TextOverflow-class.html) to see which one fits best for you. This should work if text trys to overflow over its container (into O1) it will not.